# jquery calculate the height/width of a given dynamicly filled container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a UL in it, inside of that UL via the use of jQuery I have LI elements populate it dynamically. So I can have anywhere from 1 li, to a 30 or more. If the amount of elements within the UL surpass a certain height/width when dynamically filled in I want to flip the container they reside in from a container that will stretch as it fills to one that scrolls. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When populating the list with new items, you could explicitly check the size:

```
var maxHeight = 500;
var ul = $("#myUl");
if (ul.height() > maxHeight) {
    ul.css("height",maxHeight+"px").css("overflow-y","scroll");
} else {
    ul.css("height","auto").css("overflow-y","visible");
}
```

and you can check similarly for width.

Answer (score 0):

How about just applying `max-height`, `max-width`, and `overflow` CSS style rules to your `ul` element?

```
.myUL {
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 325px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

EDIT: This solution will not work for browsers that don't respect the `max-height` and `max-width` CSS2 rules (such as IE6).

Comment: I prefer this solution if chris is allowed to pretend IE6 doesn't exist. But it should be overflow:auto, not overflow:scroll. And he wants a max-width too.

Comment: @sethobrien - Good point about IE6. And you're right; 'auto' would probably be a better choice than 'scroll'. Edited.